Fabric UI Detailist Columnwise Filtering - Textfields and Dropdowns
I am using Fluent UI DetailsList. For each individual column I would like a textfield or a dropdown filter and I have been unable to achieve that with both contextual menus or looking at other solutions.
I am fairly new to this and struggling.
I have a function to define the columns, it returns all the columns.
I have a rest API that returns all teh items which are then sent to a function to map them for a detailslist, and then the set is state in a variable.
I am using typescript which is a problem on its own.
Here's the componentdidmount function and some others :
public async componentDidMount() {
   
    let groups = await this._services.getgroups(this.props.sp);
   

    const isAdminPresent = groups?.filter(
      (group: { LoginName: any }) => group.LoginName === "Team"
    );
    

    const Admins = isAdminPresent ? isAdminPresent.length : 0;

    this.setState({
      isAdmin: Admins,
    });

    const selectParameter: string =
      "ID,SelfOrOther,RequestedBy/Title,RequestFor/Title,RequestId,Status,Created,Editor/Title,Modified";
    const expandParameter: string = "RequestedBy,RequestFor,Editor";
    const filterParameter: string = "";
    const restApiResult: any =
      await this._services.getFilteredAndExpandedSPListItems(
        "UpdateTPContactRequests",
        this.props.sp,
        selectParameter,
        expandParameter,
        filterParameter
      );

    

    const mappedItems = this.mapItemsForDetailsList(restApiResult);

    this.setState({
      items: restApiResult ? restApiResult : [],
      hideSpinnerDialog: true,
    });

    this.setState({
      items: mappedItems,
      filteredItems: mappedItems,
    });

    console.log(this.state.items);
  }

How do I render custom headers for the columns to have textfields and dropdowns for filtering ?
Tried Contextual menus but couldnt get it to do more than sorting. If I could get some help there, it would be helpful.

Don't get me wrong, I understand the project's 'requirements,' but I think it's better to create a separate filter component containing the fields displayed in the table. This solution is much more performant and maintainable than 'pushing' individual fields at the column level. The DetailsList component should serve only to display results based on the criteria entered in the filter.
